# how can I load an image on Google Drive on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-drive-api

How can I retrieve an image on Google Drive and render it onto the canvas?

Both `webContentLink` or `downloadUrl` from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files#resource) from a `gapi.drive.files.list` call fail silently.

The same call done via `XMLHttpRequest();` works ok, because I can set auothorization headers, but as far as I know I only get a blob or an arraybuffer.

And then the issue there is that - if the image is too large - the conversion to dataURL fails.

What's the workaround here?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)